How to align an image at the left side of the <div>
How to align an image to the left side of a div tag.I have a popup which display the signin section, and I wanted to add an image at the left side of the signin section. How can I do that?
html structure:
index.html
  <div id="signInPopup" class="signInPopup">
        <div class="login-image">
            {% load static %}
                <img src="{% static 'images/img.jpg'%}">
            </div>
        <div class="signInPopup-content">
            <button class="close" id="closeSignIn" onclick="closeSignIn()">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark" style="color: #000000;"></i>
            </button>
            <form action="insert" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <br><br>
                <label for="username">Username</label><br>
                <input id ="usernameInput" type="username" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username" required> <br>
    
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input id="passwordInput" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required>
                <button type="submit" name="signin-submit" id="signInbtn">Sign In</button> <br>
            </form>
            <button id="signUpbtn" onclick="openSignUp()">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </div>

I want the image to be positioned at the left side of the .signInPopup div, with the signInPopup-content displayed to the right of the image. no matter what CSS styles I apply, the image remains at the left side of the page.
CSS I'm using:
index.css
.login-image img {
    width: 500px;
    height: 650px;
}

.signInPopup,
.signUpPopup {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.signInPopup-content,
.signUpPopup-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: 650px;
    max-height: 650px;
}

.close {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    float: right;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

I have tried display="inline-block" but it is aligning both the image and the popup to the left side of the page.
Can anyone please suggest the correct CSS approach to align the image to the left side of the div while preserving its responsiveness and aspect ratio? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please take the tour, and read how to ask, an On Topic question, then look at the Question Check list, the perfect question and how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example

On a side note: Please do not use floats for layout. There are better methods now including flexbox and CSS Grid.

Please edit your question to make it clearer. For example, you say that you want the image positioned left, and then go on to say that it is in fact positioned left – so it’s not completely clear what the problem is. Include a screenshot of your actual results (how it looks now), then carefully and thorougly describe your desired results (how you want it to look). Better still, include a runnable example in a snippet.

Let’s say we want the image to occupy the left third of the popup, and the login form to occupy the remainer. I would style the popup as a grid with two columns, specified with grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr.
The image itself needs to be positioned absolutely to prevent its size affecting the popup layout.


        
body, input, button {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: gold;
}

body {
  margin: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.signInPopup {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  text-align: left;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}


.login-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.login-image img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

.signInPopup-content {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 2em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  gap: 2em;
}

.signInPopup-content form label {
  font-size: smaller;
  color: #888;
}

.signInPopup-content form input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: white;
}

#signInbtn, #signUpbtn {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  margin-right: -1.75em;
}

.close, #signUpbtn {
  align-self: end;
}

#signUpbtn {
  margin-bottom: -1.25em;
  margin-right: -1.25em;
}
.close:hover, .close:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css">
<div id="signInPopup" class="signInPopup">
  <div class="login-image">
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/id/736/500/1000">
  </div>
  <div class="signInPopup-content">
    <button class="close" id="closeSignIn"><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></button>
    <form>
      <label for="username">Username</label><br>
      <input id="usernameInput" type="username" name="username" id="username" required>
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input id="passwordInput" type="password" name="password" id="password" required>
      <button type="submit" name="signin-submit" id="signInbtn">Sign In</button>
    </form>
    <button id="signUpbtn">Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</div>



